# using complex types in a MaterialUI drop-down menu - Focus, toggling, accessibility

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accessibility

Edit: I've re-written this to clarify the issue.

I'm trying to make an accessible drop-down menu using Material UI whose Menu options are composed of elements such as check boxes and switches. In order for it to be accessible and usable, it needs to accomplish the following:

1. It must be keyboard-navigable
2. Screen readers must be able to convey each menu item's type (e.g. checkbox) and state (checked/unchecked)

I've put together a rough idea of what I'm trying to accomplish in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-silence-plczsw?file=/src/components/DropDownWithComplexItems.jsx

By setting `autoFocus` and `onClick` to `MenuItem`s as mentioned below, keyboard navigation and toggling works as expected. However, none of the element information is conveyed to the user via a screen reader (I'm using NVDA).

Is this something that can be achieved with the MaterialUI API?

Answer (score 0):

Actually pressing space on the items will work, if you console log then you will see it actually fires

`<MenuItem onClick={() => console.log("fire")}>`

If you want the checkboxes to be checked then you need to rely on `MenuItem` handleclick event and not controls from `FormControlLabel`, so a example would be

`<MenuItem onClick={() => setBoxChecked(!boxChecked)}>`

What I would suggest is adding `autoFocus` prop to `MenuItem` so you wont need to press tab for focusing items.

Comment: That does solve half the problem. Having one of the items auto-focus does let keyboard navigation work as one would expect in a menu. However, the screen reader provides no information as to what each menu item is, nor their state.

Comment: @C-Mart Do we need that information though, knowing that you can pass any callback to onClick?

Comment: Depends on who you mean by "we". Do we, as develoeprs, need that information when we can pass whatever we need through the onClick callback? Not really. But if "we" is the end-user, who is blind and is using a screen reader, they absolutely need to know what a menu item's behavior is, and its state.

Comment: @C-Mart I think we missunderstood each other and I'm a little confused of whats the problem at this point, if you would edit your main question explaining the problem you mean right now then I'm more than willing to help